# count digits in string, also return {}, [], (number)

Tags: javascript

The problem is this function counts the symbols in a string, but I need only digits. Below     my code, please help me, what is wrong here.

```
function countNumbers(num) {
  let count = 0;
  for (number in num) {
    if (typeof number.length === 'number') {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log( countNumbers('asas124') ) // 7
console.log( countNumbers('10') ) // 2
console.log( countNumbers('asasas') ) // 6
console.log( countNumbers('!@#34!@@@') ) // 9
console.log( countNumbers('') ) // 0
console.log( countNumbers() ) // 0
console.log( countNumbers(45) ) // 0
console.log( countNumbers([]) ) // 0`
```

I want a function that returns the number of digits in a string, like console.log( countNumbers('asas124') ) // 3 etc.

Comment: `number.length` returns the length of the string, which is always a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `for (number in num)` loop, which purpose is iterating over `object` props. In your case, you are using it with `string`, so your variable `number` is the index of the current string character. The type of the index is a `string` and the `.length` value is always number, so your condition is always true. Therefore, your function returns the wrong `count` value. To get the current character in `for in` loop use `num[number]` syntax. In the below example, the `if` condition uses regex to tests for numbers in `strInput`

```js
 function countNumbers(input) {
  let count = 0;
  const strInput = String(input);
    for (index in strInput) {
      if (/\d/.test(strInput[index])) {
        count++;
      }
   }
   return count;
}

console.log( countNumbers('asas124') )
console.log( countNumbers('10') )
console.log( countNumbers('asasas') ) 
console.log( countNumbers('!@#34!@@@') )
console.log( countNumbers('') )
console.log( countNumbers() )
console.log( countNumbers(45) )
console.log( countNumbers([]) )
```

However, i wouldn't recommend using `for in` loop for arrays. You can iterate over string characters and access current item directly using `for of` like this:

```
  for (let char of String(input)) {
    if (/\d/.test(char)) {
      count++;
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, you can use regex along with `OR operator (||)` for shorter syntax. The template literal "`${}`" converts input to string or empty string. `/\d/g` Matches all digits. Use optional chaining with `?` so that you get length in case of any matches, otherwise you get 0

```js
const countNumbers = input => `${input || ''}`.match(/\d/g)?.length || 0;

console.log( countNumbers('asas124') ) 
console.log( countNumbers('10') )
console.log( countNumbers('asasas') )
console.log( countNumbers('!@#34!@@@') )
console.log( countNumbers('') ) 
console.log( countNumbers() ) 
console.log( countNumbers(45) ) 
console.log( countNumbers([]) )
```

Comment: The question is _"what is wrong here"_ and I can't find the answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform, not a code writing service. It's good to answer the question.

Comment: You should reread the [tour]: _"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site"_ It's explicitly not a code writing service and requests for code writing are closed and downvoted. It's not a community that helps solving code problems. Code problems without debugging and specific question are usually closed and downvoted, see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) which is linked in [ask].

Comment: You should really read the tour and other help sites, when you want to be part of this community. It will explain, why this question is downvoted, why your answer was downvoted before your edit and what is expected of the users. If you don't like the rules, there are also Quora and Reddit.

Comment: But the professionals are going to Stack Overflow and not to Reddit. Think about it. Stack Overflow has a high quality, because low quality questions and answers are filtered out.

Comment: Yes i know. The OP question was not asked very well to begin with.

Comment: And your answer didn't answer the question before your edit.